# Retrieving data from couchDB

Tags: couchdb

I am new to couchDB but have a good experience working with relational databases. Can anyone tell how to connect to couchDB database and retrieve the data stored in it. I am giving an example in relational database and i need help regarding how to do similar task in couchDB.In mysql we use a connector to get connected to the database and the for example we give "select username from tablename where password="abc" ".

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB talks HTTP and JSON, then you can use any HTTP client and JSON parser/generator. You can find a nice introduction in [The Definitive Guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/tour.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this URL: http://localhost:5984/_utils/, it will open FUTON editor.

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB is a NOSQL database. So it works using HTTP requests (url based). Data that is stored in couchDB is in the form of JSON documents, so there is no concept of tables. In short, database in SQL represent database in couchDB and the rows in a table of SQL represent Documents in couchDB.

Coming back to your question, to retrieve data from couchDB, there is a concept called views which uses Map and Reduce functions (which are JavaScript functions). Using these views couchDB indexes your search function spanning through the complete database (includes all documents), so you need to write a Map function specifying the condition to be used to search. Here's an example -

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.password) {
        emit(doc.username, doc);
    }
}
```

The above example is a simple Map function. Search for the documents of the database where there is a password and return the usernames from all the documents in the database. Password input value (in this case "abc") should be specified in the query string that you will be sending out to couchDB URL. Now, you might ask where is the database specified to search for? I said that we have to create views in order to search. These views are stored in that particular database where you want to search. So, if you want to search a database with name "User_Credentials", then create a view in the "User_Credentials" with the above Map function. More details on how it can be done can be found here: [CouchDB Guide to Views](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html)