# CouchDB to Excel

Tags: excel, couchdb, excel-2013

I would like to import data from CouchDB into Excel 2013. Specifically, I would like to set up a connection (that can be refreshed) in Excel to CouchDB.

I know [CouchDB uses HTTP and JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646247/retrieving-data-from-couchdb), but I was wondering if there was an interface for Excel.

I've tried searching [CouchDB documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/) and [CouchDB: The Definitive Guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/) for Excel references. No luck.

What would be the best way to set up a connection in Excel to CouchDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be possible by installing Microsoft's addition PowerQuery to Excel and use the Data Explorer: http://www.angelsbiblog.com/2013/04/excel-data-explorer-twitter-search-api.html

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with PowerQuery. Just query the API vía the web function and use the editor to get the data you want.

I actually use CouchDB this way.