# Connect Excel to CouchDB

Tags: excel, couchdb

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a CouchDB database and display them in an Excel sheet.

I found a quite old thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26423913/9931226), is PowerQuery still the best option ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBA and basic auth.

Example:

```vb
Public Sub getDataFromCouchdb()
    Dim objHTTP As Object, JSON As Object
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp")
    
    user = "username"
    pass = "password"
    
    URL = "https://examples.com:5984/dbname/doc_id"
    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Encode(user + ":" + pass)
    
    objHTTP.send ("")
    
    Debug.Print objHTTP.responseText
    Sheets("Plan1").Cells(10, 10).Value = objHTTP.responseText
    
    Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(objHTTP.responseText)
    Debug.Print JSON("_id")
    Sheets("Plan1").Cells(10, 11).Value = JSON("_id")

End Sub
```

To parse JSON you can use this library:

https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

that requires this other library:

https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary